# ask about make vbulttin plugin

Tags: php, plugins, vbulletin

i started to make plugin for vbulltin but i want to ask some question

the plugin target is to allow users to deny other users from watching own profiles

my questions is

when user try to watch my profile but i deny him to watch my profile

1 - how can i show error message like

this vbulltin error

`https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/4555112245-Style-Manager-loading?p=4555112245#post637634`

2 - how can i add option in user cp [image: show like menu]

3  -  can i add new specific file to vbulltin and get info using ajax

mean : when user add userid  and click ignore

i send request to new page called `"ignorethisuser.php"`  and this page contain my php code ???